# SQL Query Performance Join with condition

Tags: sql, performance, join, where-clause

calling all sql experts. I have the following select statement:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t1.field = xyz
```

I'm a little bit worried about the performance here. Is the where clause evaluated before or after the join? If its evaluated after, is there way to first evaluate the where clause?

The whole table could easily contain more than a million entries but after the where clause it may be only 1-10 entries left so in my opinion it really is a big performance difference depending on when the where clause is evaluated.

Thanks in advance.

Dimi

Comment: If `field` is indexed there is nothing to worry about

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Give us table and index definitions.

Comment: You can add the t1.field in Join clause rather than in where clause.

Comment: I do not have a specific dbms. The product is delivered in different dbms but our standard is postgre

Comment: Be aware that indexes can be expensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.field = xyz;
```

The optimal indexes are `table1(field, id)`, `table2(id)`.

How the query is executed depends on the optimizer.  It is tasked with choosing the based execution plan, given the table statistics and environment.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your query like this:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field = xyz) t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

But depending on the database product the optimiser might still decide that the best way to do this is to JOIN table1 to table2 and then apply the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Each DBMS has its own query optimizer. So by logic of things in case like yours `WHERE` will be executed first and then `JOIN`part of the query

Comment: But, for example, MSSQL first create a temp table with the result of join, and then, execute WHERE clause.

Comment: Use MSSQL query analyzer.

Comment: Physical execution of operations in query depends on the case you have, it can't be the same for everything

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and other answers with performance the answer is always "it depends" depending on your dbms and the indexing of the base tables the query may be fine as is and the optimizer may evaluate the where first. Or the join may be efficient anyway if the indexes cover the join requirements.

Alternatively you can force the behavior you require by reducing the dataset of t1 before you do the join using a nested select as Richard suggested or adding the t1.field = xyz to the join for example

```
ON t1.field = xyz AND t1.id = t2.id
```

personally if i needed to reduce the dataset before the join I would use a cte

```
With T1 AS 
(
   SELECT * FROM table1
   WHERE T1.Field = 'xyz'
)
SELECT 1 
FROM T1
JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```